# CNContact for Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, swift, contacts, addressbook

from OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 Apple provided this framework Contacts:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328

and I would like to access contacts from Mac, but I cannot do anything, because the app does not have access to contacts:

```
switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts) {
    case .Authorized:
        print("Authorized")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "contactsAllowed")
    case .Denied:
        print("Denied")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "contactsAllowed")
    case .NotDetermined:
        print("Not Determined")
    case .Restricted:
        print("Restricted")
    }
```

The app never prompts to allow access to contacts, neither can I select it in System Preferences (it does not show up).

Has anyone any idea how to acccess them on Mac (on iOS it works well)?

Comment: Have you tried `-requestAccessForEntityType:completionHandler:`?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens...

Comment: I experienced that same issue and I had simply forgotten to set the `com.apple.security.personal-information.addressbook` key to true in the Entitlements file.

Answer (score 2):

Any call to instance of CNContactStore should trigger request. If not try

1. Reboot (actually this helped me; I was granted access)
2. Turn on sandboxing
3. Resetprivacy settings "sudo tccutil reset AddressBook"
4. Call it on main thread

Instance of CNContactStore call:

```
[[CNContactStore alloc] init];
```

> Privacy
>
> Users can grant or deny access to contact data on a per-application
>   basis. Any call to CNContactStore will block the application while the
>   user is being asked to grant or deny access. Note that the user is
>   prompted only the first time access is requested; any subsequent
>   CNContactStore calls use the existing permissions. To avoid having
>   your app’s UI main thread block for this access, you can use either
>   the asynchronous method [CNContactStore
>   requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:] or
>   dispatch your CNContactStore usage to a background thread.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I just tried my code on the new release of 10.11 and it works now! So it was maybe an issue with the beta version. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying this from the playground? This won't work.

Try this method in your project:

```
func getContactImage(name:String) -> NSImage?
{
    let store = CNContactStore()
    do
    {
        let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName(name), keysToFetch:[CNContactImageDataKey])
        if contacts.count > 0
        {
            if let image = contact[0].imageData
            {
                return NSImage.init(data: image)
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return nil
}
```

Anyway your question led me on the path to find a way to get the contacts image, so thanks for that.

Comment: Hi, no problem! ;) I just tried my code on the new release of 10.11 and it works now! So it was maybe an issue with the beta version. Thanks anyway for your help!